# How can I rename every file that matches a regex?

Tags: python, file-rename

I want to rename filenames of the form `xyz.ogg.mp3` to `xyz.mp3`.

I have a regex that looks for `.ogg` in every file then it replaces the `.ogg` with an empty string but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\New Text Document.py", line 7, in <module>
    os.rename(files, '')
TypeError: rename() argument 1 must be string, not _sre.SRE_Match
```

Here is what I tried:

```py
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        files = re.search('.ogg', file)
        os.rename(files, '')
```

How can I make this loop look for every `.ogg` in each file then replace it with an empty string?

The file structure looks like this: `audiofile.ogg.mp3`

Comment: You don't need a regex to test if one string is in another. Simply write: `if ".ogg" in file:`. That aside, clearly `re.search()` doesn't return a string. Look at the documentation for this function. It returns a match object (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".mp3") and '.ogg' in file:
        os.rename(file, file.replace('.ogg',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be far more quicker to write a command line :

```
rename 's/\.ogg//' *.ogg.mp3
```

(perl's rename)

Answer (score 0):

An example using [Python 3's `pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (but not regular expressions, as it's kind of overkill for the stated problem):

```
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path('.').glob('*.mp3'):
    if '.ogg' in path.stem:
        new_name = path.name.replace('.ogg', '')
        path.rename(path.with_name(new_name))
```

A few notes:

- `Path('.')` gives you a `Path` object pointing to the current working directory
- `Path.glob()` searches recursively, and the `*` there is a wildcard (so you get anything ending in `.mp3`)
- `Path.stem` gives you the file name minus the extension (so if your path were `/foo/bar/baz.bang`, the stem would be `baz`)